# How to speed up rendering selectOneMenu when selectItems are too many?

Tags: html, performance, jsf, selectonemenu

I have `selectOneMenu` that contains 3000 select items (I get the items from session so it's not DB performance issue) and I create the selectonemenu and add it to the view in the `init` method of my request bean, issue is that the rendering of the page is slow because the select items are too many, so I was wondering how to optimize the rendering of the page and make it fast in such case.

I am using **JSF1.1** and run my application on **websphere 7** and **IE9**.

Comment: You should use an autocomplete approche that load some choices depending on user input example 30 firsts choices starting with typed characters...

Comment: Just make use of search, filtering and/or autocomplete. No one is going to scroll through 3000 items to find the item it's looking for. Usually, endusers familiar with the system would make use of keyboard navigation for that. Why not immediately make use of it for search/filtering/autocomplete?

Comment: @BalusC stupid design is forcing me to do this, because those items are used in too many place in the code.

Comment: There are many JS/jQuery plugins for that.

Comment: @BalusC unfortunatly the OP say that the rendering is slow (probably due to data length) JS/jQuery plugins will at least fix the selection problem but the loading time will remain. I don't remember how `rich:autocomplete` or `rich:suggestionBox` works in RichFaces 3.X (which is supposed to run under JSF 1.X).

Comment: AFAIK the performance problem is caused by IE9 which isn't very good in rendering many menu items.

Comment: How does it do on other browsers ? Just out of curiosity ...

Comment: @Alexandre: uh, rendering is slow because of the many `<option>` elements inside `<select>`. IE's HTML DOM engine can't handle it efficiently. It won't slowdown the loading time or so. Just print it as a JS array variable and let JS/jQuery plugin do the job of creating/filling only a specific subset of `<option>` elements based on the characters entered so far (thus, autocomplete).

Comment: @BalusC Yes that's why I think the jQuery option wont work, he need an AJAX approche probably but he can't do it only client side of course, I just don't remember if `rich:autocomplete` work that way, just saying.

Comment: @Alexandre: uh, ajax is unnecessary. Do you in any way **understand** what's going on here?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh an option you may consider is putting the select menu in a fragment, and then statically including that fragment. This way, the browser/web server can cache the fragment. Only the first call to the fragment will take the performance hit. Subsequent calls should behave better

Comment: @kolossus: the problem is not the rendering by JSF nor the transferring of HTML over network (3000 dropdown options is as fast as a paragraph with 3000 words in spans), but it's the building/rendering HTML DOM tree by webbrowser based on retrieved HTML. IE is known to be extremely poor when it comes to large amount of children in dropdowns and tables. Thus, just transfer it over network in flavor of e.g. a JS array variable and get JS/jQuery to populate only a subset of options in HTML DOM.

Comment: @BalusC - Ah. Now I know. Damn IE.